# tomcat7-maven-plugin with self signed certificate

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I try to use tomcat7-maven-plugin (version 2.1) with tomcat 7.0.41 through https (port 443) with ssl. I created self signed certificate.

server.xml

...

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"

ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystorePass="xxx" />
```

...

However, running mvn tomcat7:deploy -X ends with error:

...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project com.systemincloud.service.connector: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project com.systemincloud.service.connector: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:556)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:636)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:477)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:923)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:367)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I imagine that this is because that certificate is self-signed. I also exported cer:
keytool -export -alias tomcat -file tomcat.cer
and import it locally but that didn't help. I don't know is it a good direction.

Thanks in advance for any clue,

Marek

Comment: I forgot about pom: <build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId><artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId><configuration><url>${url}</url><server>${server}</server><path>${path}</path></configuration></plugin>   
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: I solved ssh problem with running maven with:

    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=certs/sic-integration-connector.truststore

jvm argument. 
This site was helpful for me:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Security_Guide/ch15s02s02.html

Is there a problem to generaly mix .keytore with *.truststore ?

Comment: what was the solution? in my case, I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin to deploy my project to a tomcat9 server running HTTPS and using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @JayRajput my issue was only that when I was running a mvn tomcat7:deploy that is using a connection with tomcat manager application, it simply didn't recognized my self-sign certificate. 
It was enough to set the truststore with my cert.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite old, but as said in comment, I solved it by running:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=certs/sic-integration-connector.truststore
```

with pointing to the truststore.

Comment: I used great https://keystore-explorer.org/ to create empty jks keystore and import site's self-signed ssl certificate into it using 'Examine SSL' menu item. I know it's possible to do it through keytool and openssl, but this GUI saved me few minutes.